# Displaying sentence array outside of for loop

Tags: c++, arrays

### I'm having problem with displaying the sentence array outside of for loop

```
int example(string sentence)
{
  int i = 0;
  for (i; 1 < 50; i++)
  {
    cout<<sentence[i]<<endl;
  }
  cout<<sentence[i]<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

---

outside of for loop, sentence[i] isn't showing the character at sentence[49]
can someone tell me the reason?

Comment: That `for` loop never terminates. Post your real code.

Comment: Outside the loop i is 50. Were it 49 the loop would go for another round. Also the for statement is not properly written. 1 is always less than 50.

Comment: The for loop is pointless anyway. `std::cout << sentence.substr(0, 50);`, or `std::copy` if that allocation matters.

Comment: Your edit changed the question entirely. Please don't do that. For one, it completely invalidates the current answer. If you have a different question, the "Ask Question" button isn't going anywhere.

Comment: I revived the question

Comment: Now the question makes no sense. If this code doesn't work, it's time to change your compiler.

Comment: [Works just fine for me!](http://ideone.com/TeOTm9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
int example(string sentence)
{
  int i = 0;
  for ( ; i < 50; i++)
  {
    cout<<sentence[i]<<endl;
  }
  cout<<sentence[i]<<endl;
}
```

You want to check if **i** is less than 50, not if 1 is less than 50, because that would always be true and the loop never terminates.  Also, in the snippet I posted, **i** will have the value of 50 after the loop, so there better be a 51st element (0-based array).

Comment: I revived the question

Comment: @user3869196 You're not supposed to ask a follow-up question, especially as an edit to the original question. Just make another post if you want to ask something else.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it isn't displaying `sentence[49]` is that i is 50 after the loop runs. The `i++` in your loop increments i *after* the loop iteration has run. So when i is 49 it will run through the loop and and then increment i to 50. Then it comes around to the conditional `i < 50` and it sees that `i` is now 50 and the loop terminates. Then when you call `sentence[i]` outside of the loop it is trying to display `sentence[50]`. To get at the last character in `sentence` I would suggest one of the following:

```
cout << sentence[i - 1] << endl;
```

or the much easier to read:

```
cout << sentence.back() << endl;
```

Comment: You can't know it's the last element of sentence

Comment: Because the sample code is printing the sentence, it's logical to assume that the intent is to print the entire sentence. Which would make `sentence[49]` the last element.